# CSV file to AWS Dynamo DB design

Tags: database, amazon-web-services, csv, amazon-s3, amazon-dynamodb

I am new to AWS and am about to host a website through AWS amplify. I have some data in a csv file (about 2 million rows). I get a new csv every month with updated data. The new csv has updates to previous rows and new additional rows. There is no unique identifier for each row in the csv file as any column could be adjusted in the new updated csv. I want to store the data in a dynamo db table but I am really not sure how to go about updating the data.

A couple options I have considered:

1. deleting the previous dynamo db table and creating a new one with the new csv file (not sure about the logistics for this one)
2. don't use dynamo db and just read from the csv stored in s3 (not sure about the performance implications of reading from a csv each time I need to access the data)
3. compare the new csv with old data in dynamo db, remove entries in dynamo db that do not occur in new csv, add all entries in new csv that do not occur in dynamo db (seems like way too many comparisons given the size of my dataset)
4. just add new rows from the csv to dynamo db and ignore changes to previous rows (last resort)

I am open to any suggestions!

I have not tried any of the considered options yet.

Comment: It might be easier to consider a New SQL option of Redis or MemCacheD. This is a rough estimate of the cost: hosting a Redis or Memcached with 10MB of data, 2 million rows, and 10,000 row requests per month $10 - $15, excluding data transfer costs

Comment: Why? Or use DynamoDB which is serverless and you can get 200M requests per month for free........

Answer (score 1):

The most cost effective solution is option 1. Use DynamoDB [Import from S3](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/S3DataImport.HowItWorks.html) which provides you a simple API call to create a table and point to a data source in S3. DynamoDB does the heavy lifting of creating the table and importing the data and you pay per GB imported.

No other approach will be as easy or cost efficient. One caveat of using CSV is that all the data in your CSV file will be interpreted as strings, if that's a deal breaker, then you'll have to use an alternative method to get your data into DynamoDB such as AWS Glue or AWS Lambda.

Answer (score 0):

Since you mentioned there is no record identifier, I assume there is no `update` operation per se, only `delete` and `insert`.

If the `deleted` records are no longer there in the new CSV, and if there is no information to figure out which rows are new (like a `create_timestamp`), option 3 is quite an expensive operation. You'd have to go through **all the existing rows** in your DB to figure out which ones need `delete`. You then have to go through **all the new rows** in your CSV to figure out which ones need `insert`.

In that case, option 1 should be the most efficient option.

Alternatively, have the process that generates the CSV send you only those records to be deleted and inserted.

Answer (score -1):

I'm assuming you already have a way to import the data to DynamoDB and you get new csv file in a defined time period.

With this assumption, I would say create a TTL value for the DynamoDB records so the data will expire as defined by TTL. That way, you don't need to worry about deleting or updating previous data. (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/TTL.html). Also, import the data on the specified time period.